# C# excel interop cut and paste exception

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I’m working on a project and I’ve ran into an exception that I don’t know how to fix. I’ve searched everywhere and can’t find a solution that helps.

I’m trying to cut a range on a spreadsheet that has found a specific value in a cell in Column A and paste the entire row of that specific value into a new spreadsheet starting from A2 and until the value is no longer found in the original spreadsheet.

My code currently pastes one row in the new spreadsheet then gives me this exception “The information cannot be pasted because the Cut area and the paste area are not the same size and shape.” The exception is happening at this point in the code;

```
Excel.Range from = currentFind.EntireRow;
Excel.Range to = oSheet.get_Range("A2:A2500");
```

I think I need to use the active cell and active sheet properties.

Please help me!

```
public void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Excel.Application oXL;
Excel._Workbook oWB;
Excel._Worksheet oSheet;
if (dmCheck.IsChecked == true && fldCheck.IsChecked == true)
{
oXL = new Excel.Application();
oXL.Visible = true;
oWB = (Excel._Workbook)(oXL.Workbooks.Add());
oSheet = (Excel._Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;
string dXLPath = @"N:/DAILY2.xlsx";
Excel.Workbook dWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open(dXLPath);
Excel.Worksheet dSheet = dWB.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
Excel.Range dRng = dSheet.get_Range("B1");
dRng.EntireColumn.Hidden = true;
Excel.Range currentFind = null;
Excel.Range firstFind = null;
Excel.Range taskHazpoi = dSheet.get_Range("A2", "A2500");
currentFind = taskHazpoi.Find("HAZPOI", Type.Missing, Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues, Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart, Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext, false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
while(currentFind != null)
{
if (firstFind == null)
{
firstFind = currentFind;
}
else if (currentFind.get_Address(Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlA1) == firstFind.get_Address(Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlA1))
{
break;
}
Excel.Range from = currentFind.EntireRow;
Excel.Range to = oSheet.get_Range("A2:A2500");
from.Cut(to);
currentFind = taskHazpoi.FindNext(currentFind);
}
else if (dmCheck.IsChecked == false && fldCheck.IsChecked == false)
{
MessageBox.Show("Please check the DM and Flood box", "Report Loader");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use Epplus instead of the interop Excel (i used it).
Advantages:

- No requires office package installed in system.
- No instance of Excel in memory.
- Methods more clear.

Example of use:

http://zeeshanumardotnet.blogspot.com.es/2011/06/creating-reports-in-excel-2007-using.html?m=1

You found it in Nuget.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You try to copy an entire row into the cell area A2:A2500, that's what triggers the exception.

For the 'to' range, take `oSheet.get_Range("A2").EntireRow` or `oSheet.get_Range("A:A")`.

Comment: I tried your advice and the first option would give me the same exception but the second suggestion only cut and paste one row. I switched my code up a bit and now I'm seeing the source spreadsheet have all the rows cut but the target spreadsheet is only getting one row pasted. I believe the rows are pasting over each other. Would this be an iteration problem?